# angular custom filtering in ngTables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering, ngtable

I'm trying to do some custom filtering in ngTables (simmilar to [this example](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/11)), but with text input field. I have set of columns with standard text input filters and for some of them I want to use my own filtering function, not default angular `$filter('filter')(array, params.filter())`, but something like `$filter('myOwnFilter')(array, params.filter())`

Filtering happens in my controller:

```
var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(array, params.filter()) : array;
```

What I have:

```
<td class="text-left" data-title="'Name'" filter="{ 'Column': 'myOwnFilter' }" data-sortable="'Column'">
  {{ array.Column }}
</td>
```

and the template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ng-table/filters/myOwnFilter.html">
  <input type="text" name="myOwnFilter" data-ng-model="params.filter()[name]" data-ng-if="filter == 'myOwnFilter'" class="input-filter form-control"/>
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

As answered in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/27296677/61577 you must use a custom "comparator" function as a third argument in your controller. A simple example

```
var myCustomComparator = function(value, searchTerm) {
    return (value || '').indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
}
```

then in your getData callback

```
var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(array, params.filter(), myCustomComparator) : array;
```

Just note that you must inspect the params.filter() in case you need different comparators for different columns/fields.

The angular documentation for [filter comparator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: different comparators for different columns. How its done ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to add a filter that shows only the rows that have the property avg **greater-than** your filter:

View

```
<td data-title="'Average'" sortable="'avg'" filter="{ 'min': 'number' }">
```

Controller

```
vm.filtered = params.filter() ? filterData(params, vm.filtered) : vm.filtered;
```

And the custom filter

```
function filterData(params, data) {
              var min;
              if (params.filter() && params.filter().min) {
                  //remove default params.filter().min filter
                  min = params.filter().min;
                  delete params.filter().min;
                  //filter data by min
                  data = _.filter(data, function (d) { return min <= d.avg; });
              }
              //use the normal filter
              data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) : data;
              if (min != undefined)//add it back
                  params.filter().min = min;
              return data;
          }
```